# SQL AVG function on multiple tables

Tags: sql, average

I have two more or less identical tables:

test_score

```
id  int(11) PK AI
user_id int(11) 
module_id   int(11) 
score   double 
number_correct  int(11) 
correct_total   int(11) 
timestamp   datetime 
phase_id    int(11) 
medal_id    int(11) 
team_id int(11) 
status_id   int(11)
```

And

```
id  int(11) PK AI
user_id int(11) 
module_id   int(11) 
score   double 
number_correct  int(11) 
correct_total   int(11) 
timestamp   datetime 
phase_id    int(11) 
medal_id    int(11) 
team_id int(11) 
status_id   int(11)
```

Now the reason for these two being so identical is that they contain data from each of their own component in my system.

Now i want to use the `AVG()` function to find the average score of these two tables combined.

is this possible?

Comment: create a view with `union` and use `avg()` on the view. or without view, `avg()` function on `union`.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, average_score = AVG(score)
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, score FROM test_score1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, score FROM test_score2
) AS subquery
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Can you explain the test_score1 and test_score2?

Comment: Those are the names of your tables that have identical schemas.

Answer (score 4):

Stop thinking in terms of tables, but rather "result sets".

Break the problem into two components..

First, how do I create a "result set" of the data I want from these two tables?
Simplest solution, the **union** statement

```
select * from <table1>
union
select * from <table2>
```

Now, take the above result set and compute the average

```
select xx.module_id,avg(xx.score) as AvgModuleScore
from
(
    select * from <table1>
    union
    select * from <table2>
) xx
```

Comment: You should use a `UNION ALL`. Yes, we appear to be selecting against tables that have primary or unique keys, but if not then the implicit `DISTINCT` of the `UNION` statement will skew the results of `AVG()`.